# I want add UIBlurEffect in UICollectionView ,but no effect，it only display the image normal；

Tags: ios

**My code**

```
 UIImageView *backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:_discorverCollerction.bounds];
        backImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sea.jpg"];

UIBlurEffect *beffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
UIVisualEffectView *effectview = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:beffect];
effectview.frame = backImageView.bounds;
[backImageView addSubview:effectview];

_discorverCollerction.backgroundView = backImageView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your question to be "Why doesn't this work?".

[Read the fine manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIVisualEffectView/contentView) and see, you didn't use that right. Add the imageView to the `UIVisualEffectView`'s `contentView`.

> A UIVisualEffectView object gives you an easy way implement some complex visual effects. Depending on the desired effect, the effect may affect content layered behind the view or content added to the visual effect view’s contentView.
>
> Apply a visual effect view to an existing view and then apply a UIBlurEffect or UIVibrancyEffect object to apply a blur or vibrancy effect to the existing view. After you add the visual effect view to the view hierarchy, add any subviews to the contentView property of the visual effect view. Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself.

Comment: My English is not well, sorry

Comment: Thanks Can you answer my question, I use Google translation

Comment: If you cannot read and comprehend the documentation, I'm left only to refer you to [this kind of resource](http://www.talkenglish.com/speaking/listbasics.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
    viewBlurr.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
    UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [viewBlurr addSubview:blurEffectView];
}
```